# What is the limit on the number of rows that can be inserted in a single insert statement with PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.4 accepts multiple rows as values blocks in a single insert statement. What is the maximum number of rows that can be inserted this way?

Answer (score 7):

**It depends on how your sample "row" looks like**. In general, **RAM** and **swap** of your Postgres box will be your limit before you get out-of-memory error. For bulk insert it's recommended to:

- use `COPY` instead of `INSERT`,
- disable indexes, replication if it takes place
- tune database configuration settings in `postgresql.conf`, increase (`maintenance_work_mem`,`checkpoint_segments`)

Full list of suggestions can be found in **[Populating a Database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html)** article. In addition to this, **[Managing Kernel Resources](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/kernel-resources.html)**  and [**Resource Consumption**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html) articles are worth checking.

Comment: This is not a one-time population - I have a process that frequently kicks off a large number of inserts (currently somewhere between 50k and 100k rows, but potentially larger). I want to get this data inserted into the db as quickly as possible. It's currently done using individual insert statements, and that obviously isn't performing well.

Comment: @fields did you find any solution to your problem of handling this many inserts? any help around this would be appreciated.